# Including html page built with Angular in Wordpress page

Tags: javascript, php, html, angularjs, wordpress

I currently have a simple html page that utilizes an angular script to fetch json content and arrange it into a table. nothing all that complex.

I've been asked today to have it so that it could be included as a plugin anywhere in a wordpress site. As someone that has never used wordpress before, I'm wondering if there is a simple way to do this, or indeed if it is possible at all. Answers that I have found are either unrelated to the issue that I have, or are incredibly old.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't care about making it a plugin exactly but instead a snippet you drop into a page is fine then I would suggest using a page template that loads the angular js files and sets up the overall HTML and inits the app.